# Non privileged user can not access secondary audio device configured in asound.conf

Tags: sound, alsa, debian

I have a user called sdr that is NOT an admin.

```
sdr@mia-recorder:~$ whoami
sdr
sdr@mia-recorder:~$ groups 
sdr audio users
sdr@mia-recorder:~$
```

When I look at permissions the group audio has access to everything.

```
root@mia-recorder:~# getfacl /dev/snd/*
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/snd/by-id
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

# file: dev/snd/by-path
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

# file: dev/snd/controlC0
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/controlC1
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/hwC0D0
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/hwC0D2
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/seq
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: dev/snd/timer
# owner: root
# group: audio
user::rw-
user:lightdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

root@mia-recorder:~#
```

When I do `arecord -l` I see both audio cards

```
sdr@mia-recorder:~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3246 Analog [ALC3246 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
sdr@mia-recorder:~$ 
[/CODE]
In /etc/asound.conf I have
[CODE]
pcm.ONBOARD {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 22412334
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        channels 2
    }
}

pcm.USB1 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 22412554
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
        channels 1
    }
}
```

I have a python script that lists all audio options. It lists "ONBOARD" as an option but does not list USB1. Now if I try to run the script with onboard there is no issue however I cant use USB1. When I change to root or a privileged user there is no issue. What could the issue possibly be?

TIA.

Dovid

Comment: You've tagged this as a Ubuntu-Debian workflow or packaging issue, how does that relate to your question?  What OS & release are you using? as your question seems to be unrelated to Debian packaging/workflow as per your tag.